# increasing timer in python

Tags: python, timer, sleep

I have an infinite for loop that runs like so:

```
for I in count():
    #doing something
    savetask = savedata()
    if savetask == None:
        timerfunction()


def timerfunction():
     time.sleep(60)
```

My question or rather what I want to achieve is a function that runs like this. #do something, if savetask == None, sleep for 60 seconds, repeat for loop, if savetask == None AGAIN, sleep for 300 seconds, repeat for loop, if savetask == None AGAIN AGAIN, sleep for 600 seconds.... etc If savetask != None then I want it to restart at 60 seconds or the beginning.

Do I need to pass extra variables so that it knows that it's the second time that the function ran and savetask == None?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Edit:

Because I'm using count() and the count function is:

```
def count(I=0)
    while not finished():
        yield I
        I += 1
```

Does that mean that i increases by one each time? So maybe I could use that to count how many times the function runs and reset i if savetask != None?

Comment: why did I get 2 down votes????

Comment: where are you getting savetask from?

Comment: @Hamlett I edited my code above. Not sure it actually pertains to the problem but if it helps then good. There's a lot more code before that though...

Answer (score 1):

you can exponential backoff doing something like this

```
for i in count():
    #doing something
    savetask = savedata()
    if savetask == None:
        timerfunction(i)

def timerfunction(i):
     time.sleep(60*2**i)
```

minor stylistic point, capitals in python are typically for classes. keep variables lower cased

Comment: @James How do I reset the count?

Comment: @Dorian Pass it a 0 when u call it.